# Is it possible to set an execution timeout in a Kafka processor?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am using Kafka Streams to process some input data coming from an event and I would like to execute various boolean-returning functions on that data. The main constraint is that each processor cannot run longer than a time defined by a custom parameter `execution_timeout`. Should the execution time exceed that threshold, a default value (true or false, depending on each processor) will be returned.

I went through some questions, and even found a similar one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45115949/do-kafka-streams-have-a-timeout-on-how-long-processing-can-take); But in my case I am not using any `map`/`foreach` function. Instead, I opted for the Kafka's Processor API as I need to execute arbitrary code inside each processor.

While searching for solutions I stumbled upon the two constants

- `StreamsConfig.COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG` (`commit.interval.ms`)
- `StreamsConfig.POLL_MS_CONFIG` (`poll.ms`)

but realized they are not intended for placing an upper bound to the execution time of the `process` method.

Is there an ad-hoc mechanism in Kafka Streams for addressing such problem? If possible I would like to know if there is a solution that does not involve standard Java threads (e.g. instantiating a ThreadPool object with Futures inside it and catch an InterruptedException after some time).

Comment: There is no built-in mechanism to do what you want.

Comment: Is there a workaround then? Consisting of something different from interrupting a Java thread